# deriving from std::exception

Tags: c++, exception

i want to derive from std::exception to add specific information to my log files, but i cant figure how to access the .what() from the std::exception.

furthermore, i know that it is unsafe to create a string in my exception handler, but i'm not an expert on this topic, so what are some safer alternatives?

```
struct Exception : public std::exception, private boost::noncopyable
{
    public:
        Exception(std::string msg)
            : message(msg)
        {}
        ~Exception()
        {}

        virtual const char* what() const throw 
        {
            std::string what = message + // and now what? base.what()
            LOG(what); // write to log file
            return what.c_str();
        }

    private:
        std::string message;
};
```

EDIT:
i really have asked my question the wrong way. i'm rather interested in safety, i just thought it'd be nice to have more data for logging. i was wrong.

now, i'm not being so paranoid about bad_alloc being thrown by the message string in case there was a bad_alloc before, i'd rather have a neat message. that being said i rewrote some stuff:

```
struct Exception : public std::exception
{
    public:
        Exception(std::string msg)
            : message(msg)
        {}
        ~Exception()
        {}

        virtual const char* what() const throw 
        {
            LOG(what); // write to log file
            return what.c_str();
        }

    private:
        std::string message;
};
```

are there still any big concerns about that code now? the LOG() throws std::exception i case something goes wrong, because i didn't want an infinite loop of log calling by derived exception class, and that class again calling log which would cause the same exeception again.
Will this work like i want it to, or will a logging exception in my derived class call terminate() or cause core dump?

Comment: Re: Safer alternatives.  This is a big question.  Suitable for it's own question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It seems like you're asking *two* questions (which means you should make two separate posts). One asks how to call the inherited method from the base class, and the other asks how to store an exception message without as string (presumably because you don't want to allocate memory and incur the risk of a `bad_alloc`). Neither really has anything to do with deriving from `std::exception` in particular. Separate, specific questions leads to more descriptive question titles and more useful answers. Please consider splitting this question.

Comment: If your code throws an exception of type Exception("..."), what do you expect std::exception::what() to return? I don't think it will contain anything useful (if it contains anything at all). I would suggest simply returning message.c_str().

Comment: The return what.c_str() statement is going to be a problem since 'what' will go out of scope and be destructed. You'll be returning a bad pointer.

Comment: The right answer seems to be a mix between explaining how to write the "and now what? base.what()" part in C++, explaining that you shouldn't do that anyway as it has no useful info, and pointing out all other minor problems with this code. Let's hope the selected answer will concentrate on the first (or first two points), as that will help the OP the most.

Comment: I'm just curious if the declaration of virtual member what() in derived class will hide the non-virtual what() in base class?

Comment: @Kos: std::exception::what() *is* virtual. At least it is in VC++.

Comment: I would not recommend putting logging in what(). What would happen if what() is not called, or if it's called multiple times? Putting it in the constructor could work, but it's really not a good idea. I would put logging either at the throw site or the catch site.

Comment: I just realized that std::exception::what() does not specify throw in its signature. I'm usually very careful when overriding member functions to make sure the signatures match *exactly*, but I don't know if having a throw specifier will cause it not of override the what() function. This would be a problem if you caught it as std::exception and not as Exception.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy thanks, i'll stick to that in future

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EDIT**: Since writing this answer, I've stumbled upon the [Error and Exception Handling](http://www.boost.org/community/error_handling.html) section in the Boost document. I would recommend that document over this answer.

---

First off, making your exception not-copyable is a bad idea.  When you write something such as

```
// could be any exception, doesn't matter.
throw Exception(...);
```

The runtime creates a copy of that object into a special location.  Some compilers might optimize this and create the original object in that location, but the [The C++ Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201889544) says it's a copy, and I also believe that's what the standard says, though I'm not sure.  You might get away with this in your current environment, but that might not always be the case.

Then, everything else depends on how paranoid you are with corner cases.

The memory allocation part is mostly flaky in the exception clause (i.e. the constructor).  If this memory allocation happens to fail (i.e. `std::bad_alloc` is thrown), there are two possibilities, depending on how you write your `throw` statement:

1. `std::string` is created before the `throw` statement, `std::bad_alloc` replaces the exception you thought you would raise, problem is sort-of badly reported.
2. `std::string` is created inline in the constructor call.  If this is considered "during exception handling" by the standard, `std::unexpected()/std::terminate()` will be invoked and you basically get a core dump.

In any case, it seems like you won't get the desired effect of reporting your error.

I always recommend to create some sort of temporary state that doesn't allocate memory in the constructor and wait for the call to `std::what()` to create the string that reports the error, but that might still lead to case #1.  You could resort to some compile-time determined buffer size to make sure that doesn't happen.

Many people will tell you they've never had problems with allocating strings in constructors because it's unlikely `std::bad_alloc` will be raised unless the original exception was `std::bad_alloc` in the first place.  Hence, it depends on your level of paranoia.

Answer (score 4):

I won't go in to the myriad problems there are with your code because it's a huge can of worms.  But here is how you call a base class method:

```
std::exception::what()
```

Comment: BTW, I changed the name of your local variable.

Comment: Return value doesn't match the return type?

Comment: Don't you think that logging as a side effect of `what()` is a bad idea? Chances are you won't get any logging whatsoever, or you might get the same message logged multiple times; there's the possibility of the logging trying to throw its own exception as well.

Comment: You actually probably do not want to do this.

Comment: Using a static member to store the return value might result in hard-to-track bugs in multi-threaded programs.

Comment: @Noah, @Mark, @Sjoerd:  I don't disagree with any of you.  As I said in my comment to the OP, the question of how to do this safely is a much bigger question that warrants its own post.  All I'm trying to do here is show how to call the base class method.  I'll edit my response to show only that.

Comment: @John Dibling Upvoting your post now.

Comment: @Mark Ransom, my LOG() function does throw a std::exception, not by own base class, because i thought that would prevent infinite calls of my derived exception, am i wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question is, unless you've explicitly set the value that what() should return from std::exception then you don't want to call it.  Fact of the matter is that it's going to behave in ways you might not expect and dissimilarly on different implementations.

Note that the standard provides no functionality in std::exception to provide the string value to begin with.  Those implementations that actually provide useful information from calling std::exception::what() add additional, non-standard functionality to the class.  For example, MSVC has an `exception(char const* const&)` constructor.  This isn't in the standard and you probably don't want to depend upon it.

Your better bet is to never call std::exception::what from a derived class.  Sure, do upcalls in your custom versions that subclass things UNDER std::exception, but don't do it in direct derivatives.

If you do insist on calling this function directly then you'd damn well better check for NULL because that's what you're probably going to get.

Comment: +1 for good answer, but you didn't answer his actual question which has nothing to do with exceptions.  How to call a base class method?

Comment: thanks noah, @john, i guess i really asked the question wrong way around. i'm rahter interessted in safety, i just thought i could have more data for logging from the base class. seems i was totally wrong

Answer (score -1):

for the second part. I have several hundred kloc that runs on >100 platforms that has a std::exception derived class with std::string members. Never had any problem with it

```
class myex: public std::exception
{
public:
    std::string m_msg;
    std::string m_className;
    int m_rc;
...
```